# ِDifferent ways to use "case" in sentences

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

Suppose there are some options or solutions which are selected based on some ***cases***... What are different ways (patterns) to make a sentence with **case**?

For example:

> if it is the problem..... **in such case ?** (to refer to the mentioned problem), we should select this option ... , **in cases (or in the cases?)** (**that/in which or where ?**) we don't need this thing.... we can select this option. This option is **for [the ?] cases where ?** this thing exists...

Is my usage of **cases**, the articles, prepositions like "for" and relativizers like "where" and "that" are correct?

Comment: You show an uncanny understanding of using "case".

Comment: @ASTPace it was nice you also explained why.

Comment: I mean that you used the word three different ways and use it correctly all three times - something that is commendable for a language learner

Comment: @Ahmad can you please give more context? It's a bit hard to find out what you're trying to say. Maybe explain further?

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M I modified the question a bit. I like to learn the possible  patterns to use "case"